# Disk clone: Is it possible to speed up entire process?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, disk-cloning

I have two identical USB 3.0 hard disks (750GB). One of them is empty and i want to use it as mirror of first disk (as a backup).

Both disks are connected to USB 3.0 ports and in tests read and write speeds are quite good (~110MB/s max and ~60MB/s min for read and ~100MB/s max and ~55MB/s min for write).

I tried to do it with dd tool, like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc | pv | dd of=/dev/sdd
```

Max speed is no more than 20MB/s. Is it possible to somehow speed up it?

Comment: Do you sustain these speeds on USB when both drives are active at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a blocksize might speed thing up. E.g. `dd if=/dev/sdc bs=1M`.

Just what bs to use is hard to predict, but the default seems to be 512 byes which means that you are transferring 750GiB in 750x1024x1024x2 chucks. If you use 1M as block size then this reduces the number of chucks (and system calls) by 2048. That removes a lot of overhead.

Own testing with dd and SAS and SATA connected disks show a large increase going from 512bytes to 4K, but much smaller increases after that.

Secondly: Are both disk connected to the same USB3 controller? Then you are sharing that USB controllers bandwidth. Two different USB controllers should speed things up. (Note that I wrote controller and not USB-port. One controller usually controls several ports).

Note that: USB2 often archives speeds up to 30 or 35MB/sec. You could try moving one of the disks to an USB 2 connector and leave the other on the USB 3 port. Assuming that the USB3 port does not have the (internal) bandwidth to sustain both channels this might double your speed. (In addition to the boost gained from setting a blocksize).

Thirdly: The use of the term 'mirror' is slightly confusing. Most of the time 'mirror' refers to [RAID-1](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them) and it is possible to use two USB disk in a RAID-1 mirror. That way they always get the same content. It also means that deleting something will delete it from both drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a mirror as in RAID-1, note that this is not a backup. A mirror allows you to survive the physical failure of one drive, but does not help if you delete a file.

If you'd like to duplicate all files from one drive to another, you should consider using rsync. This will ensure that only the files are copied across, rather than copying all physical blocks. This may be quite a bit faster, depending on how full your drive is. Additionally, it is likely to be MUCH faster in subsequent syncs, as only the changed files will be copied.

If you insist on copying the physical blocks, you may want to consider copying them to a directly-attached drive first, then copying from there out to your second USB drive. This will prevent the two drives from competing for USB resources and may possibly be faster than your current approach. Obviously, this requires you have a spare 750GB on your directly attached drive.

You could consider setting up a RAID-1 configuration using mdadm. It probably won't be any faster, but it may better match what you are trying to do.